# A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception, asp.net-mvc-2

I'm using ASP.NET MVC2 and what I did didn'T help me to get rid of this exception.

I put

```
[ValidateInput(false)]
```

before the conntroller, changed web.config but again getting this exception. What I should do?

EDIT: I'm posting HTML values.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your form contains values that look like HTML such as brackets.

Please check this link: [A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81991/a-potentially-dangerous-request-form-value-was-detected-from-the-client/82170#82170)

Comment: I did everything on this question but didn't help me. And yes I'm posting a values look like HTML.